# Is there a way for me to include the React production build files without using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I would like to include React inside of my library, but I do not know how to do it. Using the HTTP module, is there a way I can recursively send static files? I would like to send the `build` folder of the React production build, but I do not know how to send all the files.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on  "I would like to include React inside of my library" ? Are you trying to return "Custom React Components" from a library ?

Comment: Basically I am trying to make a web framework, but I want to package React with it. One of the requirements however is that I have to serve React using that framework, without using Express.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have found a solution. What you can do is

````
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
      return;
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}).listen(8080);```
and serve static files using that way, or you can use the node-static module.
````